# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled

Tags: java

When I start TimerTask and then I finish, and then start again it shows this error, why?
this error:

```
[16:30:02] [Client thread/INFO] [MacroSK]: KEY_L
[16:30:06] [Client thread/INFO] [MacroSK]: KEY_O
[16:30:08] [Client thread/INFO] [MacroSK]: KEY_L
[16:30:08] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception caught during firing event net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent$ClientTickEvent@1bc14017:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at com.skelletonx.MacroSK.handler.KeybindHandler.Shopmsg(KeybindHandler.java:53) ~[KeybindHandler.class:?]
    at com.skelletonx.MacroSK.handler.KeybindHandler.onTickEvent(KeybindHandler.java:63) ~[KeybindHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_6_KeybindHandler_onTickEvent_ClientTickEvent.invoke(.dynamic) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:55) ~[ASMEventHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:140) [EventBus.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.onPostClientTick(FMLCommonHandler.java:371) [FMLCommonHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:2152) [bsu.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:1028) [bsu.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:345) [bsu.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:120) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
```

my code :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final TimerTask ts = new TimerTask(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
          Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.sendChatMessage(Ini.getIni("Loja"));
      }
    };
int delaymsg = Integer.parseInt(Ini.getIni("DelayL"));
public void Shopmsg() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ts,1000*delaymsg,1000*delaymsg);
}

@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
@SubscribeEvent(priority=EventPriority.NORMAL, receiveCanceled=true)
public void onTickEvent(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
    if(event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.END) {
        if (mc.inGameHasFocus) {
            if (keyBindings[0].isPressed()) {
                LogHelper.info("KEY_L");
                Shopmsg();
            }
            if(keyBindings[1].isPressed()) {
                LogHelper.info("KEY_O");
                 ts.cancel();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I do that when I finish TaskTime, I can start again?
if not stop, stop and restart the tasktime is it possible to pause and resume?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TimerTask` can only be scheduled by a `Timer` once.

Continuing working with `Timer`, you would need to recreate a new `TimerTask ts` each time in `ShopMsg()`.

It's worth saying though that `Timer` has been superseded by `ScheduledExecutorService` these days.  This is generally more flexible...

E.g. to create the executor (in place of `Timer`):

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Then to schedule the loop:

```
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            () -> Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.sendChatMessage(Ini.getIni("Loja")),
            delaymsg, 
            delaymsg, 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And to stop that schedule:

```
    future.cancel(false);
```

Comment: The `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` will start the loop straight away - i.e. calling the `Runnable` that you pass into it (as a lambda in the example above).  You just need to hold onto the `future` that it returns to stop the schedule later.

Comment: can you give an example ( ScheduledFuture <?> future ) 
how can I be starting the ScheduledFuture.

Comment: Hi, `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` has started the task loop.  You only need the `future` once you're ready to stop the task.  I'm guessing you're looking for a way to pause and resume this as a task though?  Unfortunately neither `TimerTask` nor the `future` have a restart or resume option - once the schedule is cancelled, it is gone.  You will need to call `scheduleAtFixedRate()` again to start the task over.

Comment: Can I rerun any TimerTask after cancelling Future object of the task without recreating the task?

Comment: there is another situation when this exception can happen as well! https://stackoverflow.com/a/69382351/7767664

Answer (score 0):

How about this closure-like approach:
(high-level code but still cute and workable)`

```
...
<inside method>
...
class NewTimerTask extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                actionToBePerformed.run();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        NewTimerTask.this.run();
                    }
                }, countOffset(morningHour, eveningHour));
            }
        }

        timer.schedule(new NewTimerTask(), countOffset(morningHour, eveningHour));
```

Answer (score 0):

I always create a new `TimerTask` instance and then schedule it with the same instance one of `Timer`. There are no issues but still I had one report from Firebase Crashlytics and I think it's related to Thread termination of timer:

[image]

So it has nothing to do with reusing the same instance of `TimerTask` cause in my case it's not possible!

So mb we need to recreate `Timer` instance in `try...catch`